# Extracting lines from continuous flow of strings

Tags: c++, string, stl, stringstream

I want to extract lines from a continuous flow of string data. But the data is not well-formatted, and I want to discard the extracted lines so that the memory doesn't go out of bound.

For example, I have serial port outputs such as this:

Batch 1

```
POS 30 10 20\n
POS 30 10 21\n
POS 30 1
```

Batch 2

```
        0 22\n
POS 30 10 23\n
PO
```

Is there a way to efficiently save the data and extract lines from it?

This is my code:

```
stringstream ss;
while (SP->IsConnected())
{
    string result = SP->ReadData();
    ss << result;
    string oneline;
    while(getline(ss, oneline))
    {
        cout << oneline << endl;
        // or do something more interesting...
    }
}
```

But my code doesn't work since getline() modifies the stringstream so that no more data can be inserted to it, and I want to keep the stringstream memory small. So I don't think I can use getline() and use something like 'popline()' instead, if it exists.

Comment: Not sure, but try calling `ss.clear()` after your inner `while()` loop?

Comment: Why not use a `std::deque` to hold the lines (each one a `std::string`)?  What you want is a "circular buffer" and the stream classes aren't designed to behave that way.  (Nor is there anything else in the standard library that does.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking hints from the comments, I came up with my own popline() that doesn't use stringstream. Thank you for the comments.

```
// like getline() for istream, but made for string and pops out the line from the input
bool popline(string& input, string& output, char delim = '\n')
{
    size_t i = 0;
    string line;
    for (char ch : input)
    {
        line.push_back(ch);
        ++i;
        if (ch == delim)
        {
            output = line;
            input.erase(0, i);  // erase the extracted line (unlike getline)
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;   // return without producing the line string when end is reached (unlike getline)
}
```

So my main function changes to

```
string st;
while (SP->IsConnected())
{
    string result = SP->ReadData();
    st += result;
    string oneline;
    while(popline(st, oneline))
    {
        cout << oneline << endl;
        // or do something more interesting...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's killing OP's first cut is hinted at by πάντα ῥεῖ.

```
while(getline(ss, oneline))
```

eventually hits the end of the `ss` and sets the EOF error flag. Once this occurs, the stream won't do much of anything until the error flag is acknowledged with `clear`.

It will also extract up to the end of the stream, grabbing any partial lines and wrecking OP's attempt at buffering the data between reads.

I'm thinking OP might want to go a bit more primitive. I usually do something like this with the `char` arrays from `read` functions. It's utterly stupid and fool-proof. Very likely this loses a few points for speed compared to a `find` and `substring` approach, but is a lot easier to get right.

```
stringstream ss;
while (SP->IsConnected())
{
    string result = SP->ReadData(); // get blob of unknown size and contents
    for (char ch: result) // read through blob character by character
    {
        if (ch != '\n') // not a delimiter, store
        {   
            ss << ch;
        }
        else // got a complete token. May have taken multiple ReadData calls
             // note that this also leaves the delimiter out of the data passed 
             // on to further parsing. Usually a good thing.
        {
            cout << ss.str()<< endl; // handle token
            ss.str(std::string()); 
            // depending on how you parse ss, you may need 
            ss.clear(); 
            // to clean up error flags like EOF.
        }
    }
}
```